# Convert timestamps when viewing logfile output to UTC offset using awk

Tags: awk, timezone, utc, logfile

I have a file with timestamps in format:
`2020-06-10 04:51:34.572 INFO: [17] Log message`

I'd like to be able to **view** the output in **UTC+{n}**

If tried:

```sh
awk  '{
  #for(timefield = 2;timefield<=NF;timefield++)
  timefield = 2

        #cmd = "date --date=\x27"TZ=UTC+7\" \"" $timefield "\"x27"
        #cmd = "date --date=\"TZ=UTC+7\" "" $timefield"
        cmd = "date --date=\"TZ=Europe/London\" "" $timefield"

#  if($timefield ~ /[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/) {
        while(cmd | getline line) {
      sub($timefield,line,$0)
    }
   print
}'
```

But am getting `awk: line 12: runaway regular expression /} ...`

**UPDATE:**
Having a lot of difficulties working out the correct *quoting*.

The correct GNU date syntax to get the timezone conversion is:

```sh
~# date --date='TZ="Asia/Bangkok" 2020-06-10 03:19:16.222'
Tue Jun  9 20:19:16 UTC 2020
```

Notice the single quote ("'") in `--date='` section. How do I correctly quote this within the `awk cmd` command?

Comment: Are you using `gawk`? If not, try `sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk` and re-run.

Comment: I've installed gawk but I'm getting into trouble quoting the cmd = correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify the time zone for the input ? is it UTC ? It will help if you can put 2-3 more lines

Comment: Try `\x27` instead of `'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That didn't work either I'm afraid.

Comment: @dash-o Not sure what I can add but I'm currently needing to convert to **from UTC to Bangkok timezone.**

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the correct quoting is annoying, given that the need to quote the `awk` script inside  a shell. From the OP comment, the goal to convert GMT time in the log file to HK time (UTC+7).

Following the OP structure, possible to do the following.

```
#! /bin/sh

awk '
{
    t_in = $1 " " $2
    cmd = "TZ=UTC+7 date -d \"" t_in "Z\""
    cmd | getline t_out
    $1 = t_out
    $2 = ""
    print
}
'
```

Worth mentioning that this solution will invoke the date utility on every line. This could be expensive for large file (10,000+ lines). If this is the case, alternative solution, using built-in awk methods can be used.

Comment: Thanks @dash-o. What would be the "...built-in awk methods can be used."? Also, what would be the $1 $2 parameters I would be feeding in here?

Comment: The $1 and $2 are the first two tokens from the file: date and time. Run the script with the standard input from the log file (<log file).

Comment: Awl has strftime to format the date, and miktime to construct a date. Much faster than calling the date program